# Как считать интервал с консоли?

Tags: java

Как считать интервал с консоли с помощью класса `Scanner`?

Есть список квартир и мне нужно вывести список квартир, имеющих заданное количество комнат и расположенных на этаже, который находится в заданном промежутке.

Моя реализация:

```
List<House> house = new ArrayList<>();
house.add(new House("1", 2, 151.36, 7, 3, "Alba Iulia", "novostroi", 2));
house.add(new House(2, 3, 127.00, 4, 8, "Centru", "novostroi", 1));
house.add(new House(3, 44, 123.10, 2, 8, "Sarmegetuza", "novostroi", 1.5));
house.add(new House(4, 24, 188.15, 1, 5, "Ghibu", "novostroi", 11));

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
             
System.out.println("etaj1");
System.out.println("etaj2");
Integer et1 = scanner.nextInt();
Integer et2 = scanner.nextInt();
int[] et = {7, 4, 2, 1};
for (int i=0;i< et.length;i++)
    if (et1 <= et[i] & et[i]< et2)
        System.out.println(et[i]);
```

Comment: Если вы можете считать одно число, что вам мешает считать два числа?

Comment: я  ввожу например 2 числа и мне должно вывести от 1 до 9 (интервал чисел)

Comment: но у меня не получается это к сожалению сделать ,если не сложно помогите пожалуйста

Comment: так а что конкретно не получается то?

Comment: Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("etaj1");
            System.out.println("etaj2");
            Integer et1 = scanner.nextInt();
            Integer et2 = scanner.nextInt();
            int[] et = {7, 4, 2, 1};
        for (int i=0;i< et.length;i++)
            if (et1 <= et[i] & et[i]< et2)
                System.out.println(et[i]);

Comment: вот как я сделала но мне ничего не выводит

Comment: Весь код добавляйте в вопрос, его же читать невозможно из комментариев

Comment: `&` - это побитовая операция, если вам надо логическое умножение, итспользуйте `&&`

Comment: я код добавила в вопрос

Comment: теперь исправьте его как я вам выше написал.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое  я и не думала что проблема в &

Comment: Пожалуйста, на здоровье.

Answer (score 2):

`&` - это побитовая операция, если вам надо логическое умножение, используйте `&&`